# Xamarin.iOS- How to implement Stepped Progress bar

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard

I have attached screen short I want to implement this stepped progress bar in Xamarin.iOS.
Please help any source code regarding to this process in Xamarin.iOS.Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom step progress bar.

```
    public class StepProgressBarControl : StackLayout
{
    Button _lastStepSelected;
    public static readonly BindableProperty StepsProperty =BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Steps), typeof(int), typeof(StepProgressBarControl), 0);
    public static readonly BindableProperty StepSelectedProperty =BindableProperty.Create(nameof(StepSelected), typeof(int), typeof(StepProgressBarControl), 0, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public static readonly BindableProperty StepColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(StepColor), typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Color), typeof(StepProgressBarControl), Color.Black, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public Color StepColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(StepColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StepColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public int Steps
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StepsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StepsProperty, value); }
    }

    public int StepSelected
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StepSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StepSelectedProperty, value); }
    }


    public StepProgressBarControl()
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Padding = new Thickness(10, 0);
        Spacing = 0;
        AddStyles();

    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == StepsProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Steps; i++)
            {
                var button = new Button()
                {
                    Text = $"{i + 1}", ClassId= $"{i + 1}",
                    Style = Resources["unSelectedStyle"] as Style
                };

                button.Clicked += Handle_Clicked;

                this.Children.Add(button);

                if (i < Steps - 1)
                {
                    var separatorLine = new BoxView()
                    {
                        BackgroundColor = Color.Silver,
                        HeightRequest = 1,
                        WidthRequest=5,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                    };
                    this.Children.Add(separatorLine);
                }
            }
        }else if(propertyName == StepSelectedProperty.PropertyName){
            var children= this.Children.First(p => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ClassId) && Convert.ToInt32(p.ClassId) == StepSelected));
            if(children != null) SelectElement(children as Button);
           
        }else if(propertyName == StepColorProperty.PropertyName){
            AddStyles();
        }
    }
    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectElement(sender as Button);
    }

    void SelectElement(Button elementSelected){

        if (_lastStepSelected != null) _lastStepSelected.Style = Resources["unSelectedStyle"] as Style;

        elementSelected.Style = Resources["selectedStyle"] as Style;

        StepSelected = Convert.ToInt32(elementSelected.Text);
        _lastStepSelected = elementSelected;

    }

    void AddStyles(){
        var unselectedStyle = new Style(typeof(Button))
        {
            Setters = {
                new Setter { Property = BackgroundColorProperty,   Value = Color.Transparent },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderColorProperty,   Value = StepColor },
                new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty,   Value = StepColor },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderWidthProperty,   Value = 0.5 },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderRadiusProperty,   Value = 20 },
                new Setter { Property = HeightRequestProperty,   Value = 40 },
                new Setter { Property = WidthRequestProperty,   Value = 40 }
        }
        };

        var selectedStyle = new Style(typeof(Button))
        {
            Setters = {
                new Setter { Property = BackgroundColorProperty, Value = StepColor },
                new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.White },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderColorProperty, Value = StepColor },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderWidthProperty,   Value = 0.5 },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderRadiusProperty,   Value = 20 },
                new Setter { Property = HeightRequestProperty,   Value = 40 },
                new Setter { Property = WidthRequestProperty,   Value = 40 },
                new Setter { Property = Button.FontAttributesProperty,   Value = FontAttributes.Bold }
        }
        };

        Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
        Resources.Add("unSelectedStyle", unselectedStyle);
        Resources.Add("selectedStyle", selectedStyle);
    }
}
```

Or you could use `Xamarin.Forms.StepProgressBar`. Install it from NuGet.

Comment: I'm Using Xamarin.iOS ...and you shared code Xamarin.form. can i use xamarin.forms code in xamarin.iOS

Comment: The code on Xamarin.forms works on ios platform.

Comment: ok and how i will use this code ?

Comment: You could create a Xamarin.forms project and select the ios platform. It supports iOS 9 or higher. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/supported-platforms?tabs=windows